"detail": "Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------460519945657845895115547;charset=UTF-8' is not supported",
Me again I learn spring boot again ! I try to create HTTP POST request with upload file . But i have this message error when i try it ont postman .
That's my file :
dto :
package com.p3_oc_fs.chatop.dtos;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class RentalDto {
    @Setter
    @Getter
    private String name;
    @Setter
    @Getter
    private BigDecimal surface;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String description;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String picture;

}

service:
package com.p3_oc_fs.chatop.services;

import com.p3_oc_fs.chatop.models.Rental;
import com.p3_oc_fs.chatop.repositorys.RentalRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@Service
public class RentalService {
    @Autowired
    private RentalRepository rentalRepository;

    public void saveRentalImage(Rental rental, MultipartFile image) {
        String imageName = saveImage(image);
        rental.setPicture(imageName);
        rentalRepository.save(rental);
    }

    private String saveImage(MultipartFile image) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = image.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/static" + image.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
            return path.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to store image", e);
        }
    }
}

controller :
package com.p3_oc_fs.chatop.controllers;

import com.p3_oc_fs.chatop.dtos.RentalDto;
import com.p3_oc_fs.chatop.models.Rental;
import com.p3_oc_fs.chatop.models.User;
import com.p3_oc_fs.chatop.services.RentalService;
import com.p3_oc_fs.chatop.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/rentals")
public class RentalController {
    @Autowired
    private RentalService rentalService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<Rental> createRental(

        @RequestBody RentalDto rentalDto,
        @RequestParam("picture") MultipartFile picture,
        @RequestParam("ownerId") Integer ownerId)
    {
    Optional<User> ownerOptional = userService.findById(ownerId);
    if (ownerOptional.isPresent()) {
        User owner = ownerOptional.get();
        Rental rental = new Rental();
        rental.setName(rentalDto.getName());
        rental.setSurface(rentalDto.getSurface());
        rental.setPrice(rentalDto.getPrice());
        rental.setDescription(rentalDto.getDescription());
        rental.setOwner(owner);
        rentalService.saveRentalWithImage(rental, picture);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(rental);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
}

}


Anyone know what i can do for fix this error ?
And I'am so sorry for my english , i'am not english i learn english also ! ^^
